# javascript extention for Firefox - querySelectorAll and classname not working together properly

Tags: javascript

Answer:
I needed to give the other elements time to load. So I added a setTimeout method around the code below.

When I try to add a **class** or **style** to *streams*, the top 4 elements in the list get the change, but the other do not. I don't know if this is a problem to do with the **querySelectorAll** or **CSS**.

Also, the **class** *node* is added to item, but doesn't add to the stream which leads me to believe that it has to do with **querySelectorAll**.

This maybe even be the fault of other classes from the site I am making this extention for.

The problem code is below:

```
var streams = document.querySelector("#sideNav").querySelector(".side-bar-contents").querySelector(".tw-relative").querySelectorAll(".tw-transition");

// putting varies attributes and moving follwed to created div
var list = document.createElement("ul");
var number = 0;

streams.forEach((stream) => {
console.log(stream);

// Stream info
stream.id = number;
stream.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
stream.className = '';

// List info
var item = document.createElement("li");
item.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
item.classList.add("node");
item.id = number;


// adding to html
item.appendChild(stream);
list.appendChild(item);
//stream.classList.add("node");
number += 1;
});
```

manifest file:

```
"manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "TFO",
    "version": ".1",
    "homepage_url": "https://github.com/obsasiyo147/TFO",
    "description": "An extention that helps you orginaize your follows in a variety of ways.",
    
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*.twitch.tv/*"],
            "js": ["TFO.js"],
            "css":["TFO.css"]
        }
    ]
}
```

How the first 4 look when code runs:

```
<div style="transition-property: transform, opacity; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms; transition-duration: 250ms;" class="" id="0" draggable="true"><div>
```

How the rest look:

```
<div style="transition-property: transform, opacity; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms; transition-duration: 250ms;" class="tw-transition tw-transition--enter-done tw-transition__scale-over tw-transition__scale-over--enter-done" id="6" draggable="true"><div>
```

I had to remove some of the elements in the list, but what happens at id 6 to the classes is what happens to the divs I had to delete do to space on stackoverflow.

The code from sideNav below:

```
<div id="sideNav" class="">
    <div class="side-nav side-nav--expanded tw-c-background-alt tw-flex-shrink-0 tw-full-height"
        data-test-selector="side-nav" data-a-target="side-nav-bar">
        <div class="tw-flex tw-flex-column tw-full-height">
            <div class="side-nav__overlay-wrapper tw-flex tw-full-height tw-overflow-hidden tw-relative">
                <div class="tw-flex-grow-1 scrollable-area scrollable-area--suppress-scroll-x"
                    data-test-selector="scrollable-area-wrapper" data-simplebar="init">
                    <div class="simplebar-track vertical" style="visibility: visible;">
                        <div class="simplebar-scrollbar" style="top: 2px; height: 593px;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="simplebar-track horizontal" style="visibility: visible;">
                        <div class="simplebar-scrollbar" style="left: 2px; width: 185px;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="simplebar-scroll-content" style="padding-right: 17px; margin-bottom: -34px;">
                        <div class="simplebar-content side-nav__scrollable_content"
                            style="padding-bottom: 17px; margin-right: -17px;">
                            <div>
                                <div
                                    class="collapse-toggle tw-absolute tw-flex tw-flex-grow-0 tw-flex-shrink-0 tw-justify-content-center tw-mg-y-05 tw-pd-y-05 tw-right-0 tw-top-0 tw-z-above">
                                    <button data-test-selector="side-nav__visibility-toggle"
                                        aria-label="Collapse Side Nav" data-a-target="side-nav-arrow"
                                        class="tw-align-items-center tw-align-middle tw-border-bottom-left-radius-medium tw-border-bottom-right-radius-medium tw-border-top-left-radius-medium tw-border-top-right-radius-medium tw-button-icon tw-core-button tw-inline-flex tw-justify-content-center tw-overflow-hidden tw-relative"><span
                                            class="tw-button-icon__icon">
                                            <div style="width: 2rem; height: 2rem;">
                                                <div class="ScIconLayout-sc-1bgeryd-0 kbOjdP tw-icon">
                                                    <div class="ScAspectRatio-sc-1sw3lwy-1 dNNaBC tw-aspect">
                                                        <div class="ScAspectSpacer-sc-1sw3lwy-0 gkBhyN"></div><svg
                                                            width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                                                            x="0px" y="0px" class="ScIconSVG-sc-1bgeryd-1 cMQeyU">
                                                            <g>
                                                                <path
                                                                    d="M16 16V4h2v12h-2zM6 9l2.501-2.5-1.5-1.5-5 5 5 5 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5h8V9H6z">
                                                                </path>
                                                            </g>
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </span></button></div>
                                <div class="side-bar-contents">
                                    <div class="">
                                        <div class="tw-flex-grow-1" id="dropzone">
                                            <div class="side-nav-section tw-flex tw-flex-column" aria-label="Organizer"
                                                role="group">
                                                <div class="side-nav-header tw-mg-1 tw-pd-t-05"
                                                    data-a-target="side-nav-header-expanded" role="group">
                                                    <h5 class="same-font">ORGANIZER CHANNEL</h5>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="tw-relative tw-transition-group">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li draggable="true" class="node" id="0">
                                                            <div style="transition-property: transform, opacity; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms; transition-duration: 250ms;"
                                                                class="" id="0" draggable="true">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <div class="side-nav-card tw-relative ffz--side-nav-card-offline"
                                                                        data-test-selector="side-nav-card"><a
                                                                            class="side-nav-card__link tw-align-items-center tw-flex tw-flex-nowrap tw-full-width tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-pd-x-1 tw-pd-y-05"
                                                                            data-a-id="followed-channel-0"
                                                                            data-test-selector="followed-channel"
                                                                            href="/arris_tier">
                                                                            <div
                                                                                class="side-nav-card__avatar side-nav-card__avatar--offline tw-align-items-center tw-flex-shrink-0">
                                                                                <figure aria-label="Arris_Tier"
                                                                                    class="tw-avatar tw-avatar--size-30">
                                                                                    <img class="tw-block tw-border-radius-rounded tw-image tw-image-avatar"
                                                                                        alt="Arris_Tier"
                                                                                        src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/85f5f83e-c20e-451c-a031-88c1cde3de5a-profile_image-70x70.png">
                                                                                </figure>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div
                                                                                class="tw-ellipsis tw-flex tw-full-width tw-justify-content-between">
                                                                                <div data-a-target="side-nav-card-metadata"
                                                                                    class="tw-ellipsis tw-full-width tw-mg-l-1">
                                                                                    <div
                                                                                        class="side-nav-card__title tw-align-items-center tw-flex">
                                                                                        <p data-a-target="side-nav-title"
                                                                                            class="tw-c-text-alt tw-ellipsis tw-ellipsis tw-flex-grow-1 tw-font-size-5 tw-line-height-heading tw-semibold"
                                                                                            title="Arris_Tier">
                                                                                            Arris_Tier</p>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    <div class="side-nav-card__metadata tw-pd-r-05"
                                                                                        data-a-target="side-nav-game-title">
                                                                                        <p class="tw-c-text-alt-2 tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-6 tw-line-height-heading"
                                                                                            title="3 new videos">3 new
                                                                                            videos</p>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <div class="side-nav-card__live-status tw-flex-shrink-0 tw-mg-l-05"
                                                                                    data-a-target="side-nav-live-status">
                                                                                    <span
                                                                                        class="tw-c-text-alt tw-font-size-6">Offline</span>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </a></div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li draggable="true" class="node" id="1">
                                                            <div style="transition-property: transform, opacity; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms; transition-duration: 250ms;"
                                                                class="" id="1" draggable="true">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <div class="side-nav-card tw-relative ffz--side-nav-card-offline"
                                                                        data-test-selector="side-nav-card"><a
                                                                            class="side-nav-card__link tw-align-items-center tw-flex tw-flex-nowrap tw-full-width tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-pd-x-1 tw-pd-y-05"
                                                                            data-a-id="followed-channel-1"
                                                                            data-test-selector="followed-channel"
                                                                            href="/maria2000">
                                                                            <div
                                                                                class="side-nav-card__avatar side-nav-card__avatar--offline tw-align-items-center tw-flex-shrink-0">
                                                                                <figure aria-label="Maria2000"
                                                                                    class="tw-avatar tw-avatar--size-30">
                                                                                    <img class="tw-block tw-border-radius-rounded tw-image tw-image-avatar"
                                                                                        alt="Maria2000"
                                                                                        src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/ecad756f-821e-49ff-92ec-555908fff485-profile_image-70x70.png">
                                                                                </figure>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div
                                                                                class="tw-ellipsis tw-flex tw-full-width tw-justify-content-between">
                                                                                <div data-a-target="side-nav-card-metadata"
                                                                                    class="tw-ellipsis tw-full-width tw-mg-l-1">
                                                                                    <div
                                                                                        class="side-nav-card__title tw-align-items-center tw-flex">
                                                                                        <p data-a-target="side-nav-title"
                                                                                            class="tw-c-text-alt tw-ellipsis tw-ellipsis tw-flex-grow-1 tw-font-size-5 tw-line-height-heading tw-semibold"
                                                                                            title="Maria2000">Maria2000
                                                                                        </p>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    <div class="side-nav-card__metadata tw-pd-r-05"
                                                                                        data-a-target="side-nav-game-title">
                                                                                        <p class="tw-c-text-alt-2 tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-6 tw-line-height-heading"
                                                                                            title="2 new videos">2 new
                                                                                            videos</p>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <div class="side-nav-card__live-status tw-flex-shrink-0 tw-mg-l-05"
                                                                                    data-a-target="side-nav-live-status">
                                                                                    <span
                                                                                        class="tw-c-text-alt tw-font-size-6">Offline</span>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </a></div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li draggable="true" class="node" id="2">
                                                            <div style="transition-property: transform, opacity; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms; transition-duration: 250ms;"
                                                                class="" id="2" draggable="true">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <div class="side-nav-card tw-relative ffz--side-nav-card-offline"
                                                                        data-test-selector="side-nav-card"><a
                                                                            class="side-nav-card__link tw-align-items-center tw-flex tw-flex-nowrap tw-full-width tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-pd-x-1 tw-pd-y-05"
                                                                            data-a-id="followed-channel-2"
                                                                            data-test-selector="followed-channel"
                                                                            href="/wetshrimp">
                                                                            <div
                                                                                class="side-nav-card__avatar side-nav-card__avatar--offline tw-align-items-center tw-flex-shrink-0">
                                                                                <figure aria-label="WETSHRIMP"
                                                                                    class="tw-avatar tw-avatar--size-30">
                                                                                    <img class="tw-block tw-border-radius-rounded tw-image tw-image-avatar"
                                                                                        alt="WETSHRIMP"
                                                                                        src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/8dd36e12-dbd4-478f-a1d4-993741bde041-profile_image-70x70.png">
                                                                                </figure>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            
                                                        <li draggable="true" class="node" id="6">
                                                            <div style="transition-property: transform, opacity; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms; transition-duration: 250ms;"
                                                                class="tw-transition tw-transition--enter-done tw-transition__scale-over tw-transition__scale-over--enter-done"
                                                                id="6" draggable="true">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <div class="side-nav-card tw-relative ffz--side-nav-card-offline"
                                                                        data-test-selector="side-nav-card"><a
                                                                            class="side-nav-card__link tw-align-items-center tw-flex tw-flex-nowrap tw-full-width tw-link tw-link--hover-underline-none tw-pd-x-1 tw-pd-y-05"
                                                                            data-a-id="followed-channel-6"
                                                                            data-test-selector="followed-channel"
                                                                            href="/jonzherka">
                                                                            <div
                                                                                class="side-nav-card__avatar side-nav-card__avatar--offline tw-align-items-center tw-flex-shrink-0">
                                                                                <figure aria-label="JonZherka"
                                                                                    class="tw-avatar tw-avatar--size-30">
                                                                                    <img class="tw-block tw-border-radius-rounded tw-image tw-image-avatar"
                                                                                        alt="JonZherka"
                                                                                        src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/6679df7d-63e9-40c2-8cb7-6509c1db10f6-profile_image-70x70.png">
                                                                                </figure>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div
                                                                                class="tw-ellipsis tw-flex tw-full-width tw-justify-content-between">
                                                                                <div data-a-target="side-nav-card-metadata"
                                                                                    class="tw-ellipsis tw-full-width tw-mg-l-1">
                                                                                    <div
                                                                                        class="side-nav-card__title tw-align-items-center tw-flex">
                                                                                        <p data-a-target="side-nav-title"
                                                                                            class="tw-c-text-alt tw-ellipsis tw-ellipsis tw-flex-grow-1 tw-font-size-5 tw-line-height-heading tw-semibold"
                                                                                            title="JonZherka">JonZherka
                                                                                        </p>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    <div class="side-nav-card__metadata tw-pd-r-05"
                                                                                        data-a-target="side-nav-game-title">
                                                                                        <p
                                                                                            class="tw-c-text-alt-2 tw-ellipsis tw-font-size-6 tw-line-height-heading">
                                                                                        </p>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <div class="side-nav-card__live-status tw-flex-shrink-0 tw-mg-l-05"
                                                                                    data-a-target="side-nav-live-status">
                                                                                    <span
                                                                                        class="tw-c-text-alt tw-font-size-6">Offline</span>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </a></div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
```

Comment: You don't need to chain those `.querySelector()` calls; you can make a single selector that identifies the elements you want.

Comment: Why not `document.querySelectorAll("#sideNav .side-bar-contents .tw-relative .tw-transition")`

Comment: I understand. I will try to add that and see if there is a change.

Comment: That didn't seem to solve my problem. the class still isn't adding to all of the list elements. thank you for the help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say there's probably a problem with your selector / page itself. There's nothing intrinsically wrong with how you've chained `querySelector`. It should behave identically to `document.querySelectorAll("#sideNav .side-bar-contents .tw-relative .tw-transition")`

I'd recommend adding a `debugger;` statement into your code & stepping through it line-by-line using either Firefox's or Chrome's dev tools to see what's happening.

One thing of note: if you set `stream.id` and `item.id` both to `number`, that's non-standard HTML, as IDs are supposed to be unique. Other sites do duplicate IDs (even YouTube) so it shouldn't cause a problem, but I'd generally recommend against it.

---

If you run the following on this page, you can see all your expected changes apply to the "Overflow Blog" sidepanel. Tested this on Firefox & there's no issue. Including adding the class of `node`, although it won't appear in your `console.log` as you're logging the div before it gets the class.

```
var ul = document.querySelector("body")
    .querySelector("#sidebar")
    .querySelector(".s-sidebarwidget")
    .querySelector("ul.d-block")

var divs = ul.querySelectorAll("div")
var number = 0;

divs.forEach((div) => {
    debugger;
    div.id = number;
    div.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    div.className = '';

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    li.classList.add("node");
    li.id = number;

    li.appendChild(div);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    div.classList.add("node");
    number += 1;
});
```

But yeah, your code itself looks fine. It may be something innocuous, like the first 4 entries load when the page loads, and then your extension runs, and then the page loads the rest of the list via AJAX. Or possibly, it's error'ing out on the 5th element for some reason. You could wrap the section with a `try catch` and log the output if there's an error. E.g. [From the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

```
streams.forEach((stream) => {
    try {
        ....
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: So the try catch isn't catching at all.

Comment: Yeah, I'd recommend adding that `debugger` statement inside your loop then. There might not be an actual error, your code looked fine to me. Run this section of script via the console (`F12`) & see by stepping through line-by-line (`F10`) whether there's not just something you're missing. You might even want to console.log `streams.length` & see that it's not just `4` for some reason. You could even look into [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to see if something else is updating them. It looks like 4+ are still getting your IDs though.

Comment: As I run through the debugger in the for loop, It looks like it only has 4 elements actually in the HTML. I think the other elements in the list haven't loaded in yet. I also learned how to use the debugger because of you. Thank you for helping me and teaching me something new today that will improve my coding ability.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one long selector

It will not be confused by other classes on the way

```js
let number = 0;
const process = stream => {
  // Stream info
  stream.id = number;
  stream.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
  stream.className = ''; // why?

  // List info
  var item = document.createElement("li");
  item.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
  item.classList.add("node");
  item.id = number;


  // adding to html
  item.appendChild(stream);
  list.appendChild(item);
  //stream.classList.add("node");
  number += 1;
};

const list = document.getElementById("list");

const divs = document.querySelectorAll("#sideNav .side-bar-contents .tw-relative .tw-transition")
divs.forEach(process)
```

```html
<div id="sideNav">
  <div class="side-bar-contents">Content 1</div>
  <div class="side-bar-contents">Content 2
    <div class="tw-relative">Realtive 1</div>
    <div class="tw-relative">Realtive 2
      <span class="tw-transition">Transition 1</span>
      <span class="tw-transition">Transition 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but still doesn't solve my problem. Unless I am miss understanding. I will try the tip and see if it fixes my problem.

Comment: Try it. but the class is still need being added to all the elements in the list. Thank you again.

Comment: I can only help you more if you show the HTML. Your code is a bit confusing since I do not know what the stream elements are

Comment: I will add the html

Comment: I want to see the HTML from sidenav, all the way to tw-transition